# virtualenv and git repo development vs production best practice

Tags: python, git, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

what would be the best practice to maintain the pip **requirements.txt** for **pkg1** , the git repo with following content

`repo/pkg1`
`repo/pkg2`
`repo/pkg3`
`repo/pkg4`

all packages are checked in one repo and **pkg1** have a dependency on **pkg2**

- how would the **requirements.txt** for **pkg1** look like?
- Is there a need for multiple versions of **requirements.txt** file? common vs production vs development? "-e editable mode"
- how to re-generate requirements.txt file when an environment have editable package installation example of URL generated locked to specific git commit:

  *-e git+ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git@562ba58a6b98a29fe0914428c097f#egg=pkg1&subdirectory=pkg1*
- apparently relative paths are broken in pip, how to specify **pkg1** and **pkg2** in edit mode in the **requirements.txt** ?

  - packageA=1.0
  - packageB=3.4
  - packageC=3.5
  - -e .
  - -e ../pkg2

example requirements.txt file generated:

```
colander==1.0
cryptography==1.4
docutils==0.12
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/username/project1.git@562ba58a6b98a29fe87877289d2abc24eb8c097f#egg=frontend&subdirectory=frontend
gunicorn==19.3.0
schedule==0.3.2
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/username/project1.git@562ba58a6b98a29fe87877289d2abc24eb8c097f#egg=shared&subdirectory=shared
shellescape==3.4.1
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
transaction==1.4.4
translationstring==1.3
venusian==1.0
waitress==0.8.10
```

in this example **pkg1** is *frontend* and **pkg2** is *shared*

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? If you're using a virtual environment, generating the requirements is just `pip freeze >> requirements.txt`

Comment: updated with more specific data

Comment: relative paths should work: `pip install -e ../pkg2`; if pkg2 happens to contian a .git, `pip freeze` wil show a git link.